# Should I create a contentprovider in my Android project that uses Firebase & Sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, android-contentprovider

I'm making an android project that will use both Firebase (cloud) & Sqlite to store my data.

In this scenario, is it a good idea to create a contentprovider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application won't communicate with another apps, you don't need any content provider in this case, because you are using Firebase and Sqlite also together. You can use Firebase for your online operations and you can use Sqlite to manage your offline operations. Firebase offline capabilities may be a solution for you also or you can make a custom solution, Firebase and Sqlite together. Please check documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

You need Content provider, when you want to share your data with other apps. If your scenario doesn't have any data that is being provided to or being shared with other apps, you don't need content provider.

Additionally you can share your Firebase database with other applications via Firebase Console settings. You can create one Firebase Realtime Database and share it with many other applications. You truly have many options, you have to decide what you need in your scenario and decide on a particular way from many alternatives.

If you need to share your data with another application, please check this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html

Answer (score 1):

**No**, I don't think so that there is any role of Content provider in your Firbase(cloud) and SQLite. because **Content Provider** is used to provide our application data with other application But in your case there is no need to share your data with other application. for more knowledge you may go through the [official website of  android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html).